# How do I prevent my a touch device from executing an ::hover instead of a click function?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, ios, css

Okay, this might be a common problem, but I haven't found a solution by now.

I have a tile on my website, acutally a div container where I want to add a "touched" class if I click on it form a touch device.

Everything works good besides that on the first tap, it doesn't execute my click function, but the ::hover. After the first tap, everything works as expected.

This is some code

```
function init() {
        $tile.on('click', toggleTouchClass );
    }

function toggleTouchClass(){

        if( $('html').hasClass('isTouch') ){
            $tile.toggleClass('touched');
        } else{
            return
        }
    }
```

init is called when the document is ready of course.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should subscribe to the `touchstart` event on touch devices:

```
var isTouchDevice = ... // You can check ontouchstart in window object or use Modernizr.touch to set this
$tile.on(isTouchDevice ? 'touchstart' : 'click', function() {
    ...
});
```